# How to execute command after CP command in bash?

Tags: bash, echo, cp, udev

I trying to make script to execute when USB plugged in with `udev`. But I got an issue: Runing script manually is working good as I expected. But when I run automatic(USB plugin), the command after `cp` not working and all files have been copied successfully. 
This is my scipt:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /media
echo "Mounted USB" > /dev/ttymxc0

cp *.mp4 /media
echo "Transfer successfully" > /dev/ttymxc0
umount /media
```

Transfer successfully - is not display and USB not unmounted.
What should I do ?

Thank you so much !

**NOTE**: I try with some file 20MB is working good. But when I try with 20 files, I get that error. All file had been copied but other command after `cp` command are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Do proper error handling.

```
if mount /dev/sda4 /media
then
  echo "Mounted USB" > /dev/ttymxc0
else
  echo "Can not mount" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if cp *.mp4 /media
then
  echo "Transfer successfully" > /dev/ttymxc0
else
  echo "Can not copy" >&2
fi

if umount /media
then
  exit 0
else
  echo "Can not unmount" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Well, I tried follow your guide. But issue is not solved. I think the main problem is time execution, if exceed a time, it will not continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
mount /dev/sda4 /media
echo "Mounted USB" > /dev/ttymxc0

cp *.mp4 /media
echo "Transfer successfully" |  tee -a /dev/ttymxc0
umount /media
```

From `man` page

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

You are redirecting output to file.

Comment: I tried follow your guide. But It's also not working.